# Adding MvvmCross nuget package reference to PCL failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Simple task leads to error. I'm trying to create new PCL lib with mvvmcross reference.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/profile.png

Then I'm adding nuget reference:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/mvvmcross_monodroid_pcl.png

Profile selection exactly the same as at MvvmCross demos but it doesn't work.
Possibly it is because when I select .net 4.5 & wp7.1 it goes back to .net 4.0 and wp7.0 but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Probably I have to manually setup Profile in PCL .proj file but I don't know what the number should I write there? Current profile is "Profile8"

Thank you for any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the profile you want is Profile104.  You need to copy the MonoTouch and MonoAndroid XML files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104\SupportedFrameworks`.  Then when you choose the frameworks you have selected in the screenshot it won't automatically select .NET 4 and WP 7.0.

Comment: I have both xml files in place: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/profiles.png and on initial screenshot (from the question above) they are selected. Could you please clarify how did you get Profile104? Are there any calculation rules, reference table, etc? I just tried to specify 104  and it allows to add nuget but with this profile MonoTouch and MonoDroid platforms are excludeded and I couldn't add reference to my MonoDroid/Touch app to this PCL lib.

Comment: @DreamTeamMobile: How to get to Profile104: In the choose target frameworks dialog, choose everything you want except MonoTouch and Mono for Android.  Then in the references node of your project select ".NET Portable Subset" and look at the value of the Path property in the properties window.  That will tell you which profile you are targeting, and that's the one you should add the Mono XML files to.

Comment: It was interesting fact that I should add those xml for every portable profile I support. Now I know where to get list of all supported profiles. And I was able to choose required profile and create valid PCL with MvvmCross for my Droid app. Thanks!